Why are there two secrets in the ZKP nullifier construction?
Tornado Cash makes use of ZKP and nullifiers to prevent double spending.
Why is the submitted hash for the Merkle tree is that of concat(nullifier, secret) instead of concat(secret, 0x01) and the nullifierHash is the hash of concat(secret, 0x02) ?
What is the cryptographic rationale for having two secrets (nullifier and secret)?
